# Our designer refuses to work because of job official title

Tags: character, project-management, teamwork

Our game contains comics to tell part of the story, and our comic designer says that he is not responsible for designing the characters in the comics because it is the job of the character designer.
Is what he said true?
As far as I know the comic designer is responsible for everything that is in the comics, regardless of the design content.
Excuse me if I'm not using official job titles here (like a "comic designer"?! is there even such title)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is exactly why both parties should agree on an official job description.

Comment: This looks to be a question about workplace management, not a question about game development. Your workplace happens to have the purpose of making a game, but the problem you want help with has to do with managing people, not with making/testing/deploying game assets or code. So, you might want to ask this on [the Workplace StackExchange](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) instead. They have traffic from experts in managing people. We have traffic from experts in creating game assets / code / etc.

Comment: Side note about job title: they mean whatever the company wants them to mean. And some of them overabuse this...

Answer (score 4):

Job titles and responsibilities vary greatly from one place to the next. The duties for a particular role at a particular place depend on what the two relevant parties have agreed upon. The particulars of that (such as authority of a manager to assign additional responsibilities, legal ramifications, and so forth) extend beyond the bounds of game development.

Game development teams often have overlapping roles and require a certain amount of fluidity, especially on small teams.

Both options you described sound reasonable. That is to say, designing characters for the comic content could reasonably be assigned to either role, or possibly even both.

Game development roles are not externally regulated. As such, "known title duties" only makes sense in the context of a contract of some kind. For instance, hiring documents, certain verbal agreements or task assignments from a manager. That's not something we can arbitrate.

Comment: Nice explanation, but forgive me for the silly question, and if there is no agreement can the character designer design the comics characters according to the known title duties?

Comment: @KinanGH I've updated in an attempt to clarify that you're specific question about known title duties isn't something that we can arbitrate. It depends on things internal to your company. There's no "official" set of job definitions to be applied here.

Comment: I disagree this question is opinion based. It's a real world problem. There may not be an objective answer, but there are subjective answers that are not just opinions.

Comment: @Escoce I don't understand your comment in the context of either my answer or the comments on my answer - neither said the question was opinion based. I also didn't vote to close it, so I'm not sure why you commented as you did here. Did you mean to post a comment on the question itself? Even though the closure reason is "opinion-based" the consensus seemed to be that it's more appropriate for the Workplace SE than the Game Dev SE.

Answer (score 2):

Most job descriptions include a final catch-all clause that says something like "and any other duties as assigned or required."

It is one thing to say, "I don't have the skillset to do that job, and I am concerned about producing a quality product." It's another thing to just outright refuse to do something just because they don't want to do it.

Someone refusing to do work because it doesn't align with their job title or exactly matches their job description is a problematic employee and should be replaced. That person is not looking out for the company's best interests.

Comment: That answer is really dependant on the country.
In mine, an employment contract is a two-party contract and an employer trying to get employees to perform tasks not in their job description is problematic and can get sued.