# What do "Character Designers" do in the game industry?

Tags: character, art, game-industry

I'm curious about character designers, do they design characters in game related images like wallpapers or something like these :
[image: Guacamelee]

[image: Darksiders]

[image: Hollow Knight]

[image: Celeste]

Answer (score 2):

The task of "character design" is to take a character idea from a game designer and then come up with how that character could look. Which requires to visualize that look in some artistic medium. They usually go through several iterations. They create a rough sketch, ask the team for feedback regarding what does and does not work about the character, and then create more sketches until the team figured out the final look of their cast of characters.

One could consider "character designer" as a subset of "concept artists": People who come up with how things could look and then create images for internal use. The artworks they produce are usually not supposed to be seen by the public (although a particularly good piece of concept art might *occasionally* find its way onto a loading screen or advertisement banner). They primarily serve as reference for those artists who create the actual game assets or promotional material: 2d artists and 3d artists.

But in practice there is usually a lot of overlap between character design and other disciplines of game art. Especially in smaller teams, where people tend to wear many hats at once. In a smaller team, it might be just one person who comes up with the character and then skips the concept stage and creates the game-ready assets for that character right away. Or if there is a dedicated concept artist, then they might create concept art for all kinds of things in the game, not just characters.

Comment: Thanks, I understood from you that character designer's work may overlap with concept artist's.

Comment: @KinanGH What I actually wrote is that character designers are a sub-specialization of concept artists.

Comment: And concept art is the process of sketching every asset that is required in the game, right?

Comment: @KinanGH Every asset that warrants to go through an iterative design process before you start to create game-ready assets. Creating a concept art sketch for every little detail which can just as well be improvised by the artists is usually not worth the effort. And it's a complete waste of time when you want to recreate an object which exists in the real world, because then you can just use a reference photo.

Comment: I get that, but honestly I don't see the answer to my question .

Comment: you told me of the overlap between the character designer and concept art works, but not if he is responsible for creating characters that promotes inside promotional assets or loading screens.

Comment: @KinanGH "The artworks they produce are usually not supposed to be seen by the public (although a particularly good piece of concept art might occasionally find its way onto a loading screen or advertisement banner)"

Comment: but that is the work of concept artist not character designer.

Comment: @KinanGH As I wrote, a character designer **is** a type of concept artist.

Comment: @KinanGH By the way, I read your question [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/194965/our-designer-refuses-to-work-because-of-job-official-title). When you have a conflict in your team regarding who has which responsibilities, then I would advise you to solve that conflict by talking to each other and finding a solution which works for your team, not by looking for validations from anonymous strangers on the Internet to find out who is "right" and who is "wrong".

Comment: I'm not looking to prove someone right or wrong, we want to solve this problem by asking professionals in the field (not "anonymous strangers") that know the standards or can help us find the answer, thank you by the way.